# How to sync the progress reading of ebooks from android?

Tags: sync, ebooks

There are Android apps wich use dropbox or google drive for syncing the reading progress of ebooks. Is there any app or software for syncing the progress in Android and Ubuntu?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try [Calibre](http://calibre-ebook.com/). You can install it using apt-get

`sudo apt-get install calibre`

Comment: I know Calibre. But Calibre does not sync reading progress.